WSL losing all its setup when device is re-booted
I had completed all my setup like installing cuda and docker over my device and then was done for the day.
The next day when I come back, to my dismay I am unable to find any of the changes which I made post booting up my device and from then on I am looking for why this is happening and how do I make it retain all the installation and changes to config. But every time I am getting disappointed.
Need help in understanding the issue and resolving it.
when I ran wsl during bootup running

wsl -l -v

returns
   NAME      STATE           VERSION
 * Ubuntu    Stopped         2

As I have setup a task which runs

wsl --shutdown

during bootup.
And when running

wsl --version

WSL version: 2.1.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.3374


Try as administrator to run the following commands: wsl --update and wsl --shutdown.

Do you close your WSL sessions before shutting down or do you shutdown with everything open?

I scheduled a task which run when system boots up to run wsl --shutdown. But that didn't help. @cup I dont close it before shutdown explicitly.

Welcome to Super User!  Can you edit your question to include the following -- (1) Output of wsl -l -v (2) Output of wsl --version (if it just outputs the help, that's useful information as well) (3) You mention using Docker - Is this Docker Desktop or Docker Engine? Thanks!

Is there any chance that you are on a corporate system that might reset user AppData on reboot?

updated it above.
This is my system so no.
But your idea in a way worked I was tired so just did a hard rest of the system and post a nightmare I was able to run all things fine.

@ArunbhYashaswi Good to hear that you are back up and running.  Unfortunately your question is the third time I've seen something similar asked here and on Ask Ubuntu, and in no case have we been able to solve it yet. :-/  The other two were corporate or university systems, though.

I think it in regards to either some corruption of file. Like in my case I would say that I had disabled virtual env through bios as I was not able to underclock my system for a task. And I was opening this setup post reactivating it again, things to note my  device had wsl 2 installed prior to it. I am thinking somewhere along the line went wrong and I am unable to put a finger on it.
